# Half open interval [0,2), showing it isn't compact

Tags: general-topology

How do I find a example of an infinite open covering of [0,2) showing it isn't compact. I would be able to do it if it was (0,2] using 1/n. But I don't know what to use here.

Comment: The function $f(x) = 2-x$ is a homeomorphism between $(0,2]$ and $[0,2)$.  So just apply $f$ to your infinite open cover of $(0,2]$.

Comment: A compact set has to be bounded, show that if $g(x) =1/(x-2)$ is a real valued function on $[0,2)$ then the image of $g$ is not bounded. Thus $[0,2)$ cannot be compact since the image of a compact set has to be compact.

Answer (score 3):

Just use $[0,1) \cup \bigcup \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(2 - \frac{2}{n}, 2) $.

Comment: How can $0$ be in that union?

Comment: @Riccardo Allegrone,  your are right but it is easily fixed by adding one more subset (I edited the post).

Comment: $1$ is not in your proposed covering. Why not just use the covering by the open sets $[0, 2 - 2/n)$?

Answer (score 3):

Let $$A_{n} = (-1,2-\frac{1}{n})$$ with $n \in \mathbb{N}^+$. Notice that $A_n \subset A_{n+1}$.

Then,

$$[0,2) \subseteq \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n.$$

Suppose $\exists k, i_1,\ldots, i_k \in \mathbb{N}^+$ such that $$[0,2) \subseteq A_{i_1} \cup A_{i_1} \cup \dots \cup A_{i_k} = A_{\max_{j}i_j} = (-1,2-\frac{1}{\max_{j}i_j}).$$

Then you would have $$2 \le 2-\frac{1}{\max_{j}i_j} \implies \frac{1}{\max_{j}i_j} \le 0 \implies 1 \le 0.$$

So $\{A_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}^+}$ is an open cover of $[0,2)$ from which you can't extract a finite subcover.

Comment: For the last line of the equation, excluding the summary, how is 2 less than 2-1/max. Would 2 always be greater or equal to it?

Comment: Yes! We could stop there, since we had already reached an absurd! I just made the absurd more explicit.